# position of ion-popover over ion-modal

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

I'm trying to display an information popover within the already opened modal.
However the popover doesn't display in the right location. Even when the event is passed to the popoverController the location isn't correct.

Is it possible to display the popover just under the information button?

The code within the modal, where i call the popover:

```js
const popoverElement = Object.assign(document.createElement('ion-popover'), {
      component: 'info-popover',
      event: event,      
    });

document.body.appendChild(popoverElement);
return await popoverElement.present();
```

Screenshot of Popover above:

[image]

**EDIT**

This is what the DOM looks like. As you can see the modal is attached to `body` > `app-root` > `ion-app`. And the popover is attached just to `body`
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Turning off the shadow DOM in stencil can solve this issue, however I would prefer not to.

```js
@Component({
  tag: "component",
  styleUrl: "component.css",
  shadow: false
})
```

Comment: I recently had a similar problem. Can you check where `ion-modal` and `ion-popover` are attached to the DOM? They should both be direct children of `ion-app`.

Comment: The ion-modal is attached to the body > app-root > ion-app, while the ion-popover is  attached to the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `target` property of the click event is the shadowed parent, not the clicked item itself so it [sets the wrong popover position](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/popover/animations/ios.enter.ts#L20).

Since you manually pass the event, a workaround would be to manually set the `target`. But because it's a read only field you need to do this with `Object.defineProperty` (replace `theClickedElement`):

```
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {value: theClickedElement})

const popoverElement = Object.assign(document.createElement('ion-popover'), {
  component: 'info-popover',
  event: event,      
});
```